# функция if elif else python

Tags: python, if

```
 numOne = int (input('Введите первое число: '))
Введите первое число: 8
>>> numTwo = int (input('Введите второе число: '))
Введите второе число: 7
>>> if numOne > numTwo:
    rezult = numOne - numTwo
elif numTwo> numOne:
    rezult = numOne + numTwo
else:
    rezult = numOne
    print('Итоговое число:', rezult)
```

Пытаюсь выполнить такую простую задачку, но при нажатии `enter`, результата нет. Почему?
И еще у меня проблемы с пробелами в функциях `if, elif, else`. Самостоятельно выставляет пробелы и от этого происходит ошибка

> `unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Приходится методом тыка приходится искать правильное положение. Посоветуйте пожалуйста хорошую статью,отрывок касающийся именно этих функций

Answer (score 4):

Следите за отступами! Обратите внимание на последнюю строку и отступы (вернее - их отсутствие) в ней.

```
numOne = int (input('Введите первое число: '))
numTwo = int (input('Введите второе число: '))
if numOne > numTwo:
    rezult = numOne - numTwo
elif numTwo> numOne:
    rezult = numOne + numTwo
else:
    rezult = numOne
print('Итоговое число:', rezult)
```

В вашем варианте вывод должен быть только при равенстве первого и второго числа. В моем - всегда.

Answer (score 0):

Привет.
Хм.. очень странно, но почему то не нравится переменная rezult. Вот так работает:

```
numOne = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
numTwo = int(input('Введите второе число: '))
if numOne > numTwo:
    r1 = numOne - numTwo
if numTwo > numOne:
    r1 = numOne + numTwo
else:
    r1 = numOne
    print('Итоговое число:', r1)
```

Comment: Как именно определили, что работает? Как определили, что "не нравится" переменная rezult? Чем именно не нравится?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, если ввел в заблуждение, переменная rezult ни причем. Ошибка в исходном коде, то что print относиться к else, поэтому и при вводе 8 и 7 print ничего не выводит

Comment: А ваш код выводит, но совсем не то, что нужно ;)

Comment: Да, я это и написал:)